# C# How to XOR all int elements of an array after reading from console?

Tags: c#, arrays, console, xor

My real purpose is to get the only array element that appears odd number of times. So I found out it can be done via XOR-ing all elements of the array. Like this:

```
int[] arr = { 3, 4, 7, 7, 0, 4, 0, 7, 3 };
Console.WriteLine(arr[0] ^ arr[1] ^ arr[2] ^ arr[3] ^ arr[4] ^ arr[5] ^ arr[6] ^ arr[7] ^ arr[8]);
```

The problem however is that the array is not given, but is being read from the console, thus I don't know how to XOR the elements after they are entered. The code I could work out so far is:

EDIT: I managed to finish the code properly, thanks to your help.

```
static void Main()
        {                
        int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        long[] rectArray = new long[N];           

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            rectArray[i] = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        long initial = rectArray[0]; 
        for (int i = 1; i < rectArray.Length; ++i)
        {
            initial ^= rectArray[i];
        }            
        Console.WriteLine(initial);
        }
}
```

P.S I'm real noob, so please be patient! :)

Answer (score 17):

Along the same lines as Esailija's answer, but using `foreach` - taking advantage of the fact that `0 ^ x == x` for all values of `x`:

```
int current = 0;
foreach (int value in array)
{
    current ^= value;
}
Console.WriteLine(current);
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, LINQ's `Aggregate` method will do this too - and as we're happy to use the first two values in the first step, we don't even need to provide a seed:

```
int xor = array.Aggregate((x, y) => x ^ y);
```

Comment: Would `arr.Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a ^ b)` be equivalent?

Comment: @vcsjones: Yes it would, but I got distracted before I could post it. And I find `Aggregate` cumbersome compared with the rest of LINQ. Post it yourself as an answer :)

Comment: @vcsjones: In fact, we don't even need to provide the seed. See my edit :)

Comment: Your int xor = array.Aggregate((x, y) => x ^ y); suggestion was something new for me and I'm trying to understand it, but how exactly can I implement it in my code?

Comment: @Todo: I'm not sure what you mean by "implement it" in this case - you add a `using` directive for the `System.Linq` namespace, and then the code in my answer is everything you need. You should read up on LINQ though, to properly understand what it's doing.

Comment: @Jon: I meant how to print the odd appearing element on the console, but I figured out this should be the int xor...

Answer (score 12):

You could write a loop:

```
int initial = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i ) {
    initial ^= arr[i];
}
Console.WriteLine( initial );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 0; i < rectArray.Length; i++)
{                      
    sum ^= rectArray[i];
}
```